# Difference between {{ url('/task') }} and {{ url ()/task}}?

Tags: url-routing, laravel-routing, laravel-5

Hi i am using Laravel 5 on a previous project while writing blade template i used the form action as

```
<form action="{{ url() }}/task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

But in my recent project i am using the same format but the code is giving error

> Htmlentities()expect parameter 1 to be string object given.

If i write like this

```
<form action="{{ url('/task') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

the code is working can any one help me understand the difference and how can i fix it

Comment: See this 


  [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data

Comment: This isn't what i asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url()` is a helper function. It returns a fully qualified URL to a given path (a string) or an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator` class (an object). You can see how it works out there - `src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

So, when you run `{{ url() }}` in your template you simply ask template engine to apply a `htmlentities` function to an object.

Prior to Laravel 5.2 (in 5.1 and less) the `url()` helper function always returns a string:

```
function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null)
{
    return app(UrlGenerator::class)->to($path, $parameters, $secure);
}
```

Now, they handle if a first parameter is null

```
function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null)
{
    if (is_null($path)) {
        return app(UrlGenerator::class);
    }
    return app(UrlGenerator::class)->to($path, $parameters, $secure);
}
```